# Program not initializing extern variable in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize an empty 2 dimensional array of pointers that point to data structures I have created known as "node"s. For some reason, I'm getting this scoping issue when I'm trying to modify the list, which is a crucial part of the program. A function called "repository_init" is supposed to truly initialize the array. However, I am using the array in other functions, which is why I'm getting the error. It doesn't recognize that the array exists. I'm new to C but after doing some research I found something on "extern", and the site told me that I could use extern to declare an empty variable. So, I declared my list as a global variable by putting it before main and writing it like so:

```
    extern node *main_list[][];
    #define MAX_LEVEL 10000
```

Here is the repository_init() function:

```
     void repository_init(int p){
         int new;
         new  = (max_range/2) + 5;
         max_height = 1;
         while(new > 1){
            new = (new * probability)/100;
            max_height++;
         }

         main_list[max_height][MAX_LEVEL];

         /*fill the array with empty values*/
     }
```

The error output to the screen is "error: array type has incomplete element type

extern node *main_list[][];"

I need this list to be global. I don't see what the problem is with just having the array initialized in a separate function. I've done this tons of times in other languages.

Comment: If you want to set the size later you need to store it as a node*** and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is twofold: The first is that the declaration of `main_list` is incomplete, just as the compiler is telling you. You need sizes for the array(s) when declaring an array. The second problem is the *expression* `main_list[max_height][MAX_LEVEL];` which uses this incomplete array. It doesn't set the sizes, it tries to access the array(s).

In your case it's probably best solved by having pointers to pointers. Something like

```
extern node ***main_list;

...

main_list = malloc(sizeof(node **) * max_height);
for (size_t i = 0; i < max_height; ++i)
    main_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(node *) * MAX_LEVEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

What your declaring is not a array.

`It's a pointer to 2D array`. You can't declare a pointer to a 2D array without defining its size(at least rows while using pointers concept).

If you want 2D array declare it as following:-

> extern node main_list[][];

If you want a pointer to 2D try using a triple pointer

> extern node ***main_list;

Note:- array size is calculated at compile time so compiler has to know its size.

Answer (score 0):

From `C99` standard, section 6.2.5, article 20 -

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
>   objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.
>   Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number
>   of elements in the array. An array type is said to be derived from its
>   element type, and if its element type is `T`, the array type is
>   sometimes called `array of T`.

It furthers says in the footnote #36 -

> Since object types do not include incomplete types, an array of
>   incomplete type cannot be constructed.

This means that conceptually there's no difference between 1-D array and 2-D array etc. They are all the same type - the `array type`. The following statement

```
extern node *main_list[][];
```

is intended to **declare** an array `main_list` of type `node *[]` of unknown size. 
The type `node *[]` is itself an array type but its size is not know and hence it's an incomplete type. You can declare an array of unknown size which will be resolved with its external definition, but **you cannot declare an array of incomplete type** as clearly stated in the standard which is quoted above. The type of the array element must be a complete type. This explains the error statement.
Here is what I suggest -

```
// header file myheader.h

#define MAX_LEVEL 10000

extern node *main_list[][MAX_LEVEL];
```

I would suggest not to use variable names like `new` which is a keyword in many languages and may cause confusion. Also, you can initialize your array with `NULL`.

```
// myfile.c

void repository_init(int p) {
     int newval;
     newval  = (max_range / 2) + 5;
     max_height = 1;
     while(newval > 1) {
        newval = (newval * probability) / 100;
        max_height++;
     }

     // definition of the array. specifies the array size 
     // and allocates memory on the stack. size is resolved with
     // the extern declaration of the array main_list.
     // initialize all elements of the array to NULL. 

     node *main_list[max_height][MAX_LEVEL] = {0};  

     // process the array main_list
 }
```